# Display Boolean enum value

Tags: visual-c++, enums, boolean

Having issues with displaying the values of a Boolean type enum. The book I am using has left me in the cold concerning enums of bool type.

While I can define it:

```
enum class WeekDays : bool { Mon = true, Tues = true, Wed = true, Thurs = true, Fri = true, Sat = false, Sun = false };
```

I am unsure how display it under the int main() function and tried many times to no avail. I can however use the other enums just fine and understand what they are doing, for example:

```
enum class Suit{Clubs = 1, Diamonds = 2, Hearts = 3, Spades = 4};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
Suit suit = Suit::Clubs;
int value = safe_cast<int>(suit);
Console::WriteLine(L"Suit is {0} and the value is {1} ", suit, value);
```

Comment: I don't *really* see how useful an enum like that would be. However, to get to your problem - why are you even bothering to convert your enum to an int at all? Cast it as a bool if you know that's the correct type.

Comment: I understand it needs cast as enums are generally int type but how would I display the result of the WeekDays enum?

Comment: "How would I display the result of WeekDays enum?" - if you mean how do I output the value (true/false), like I said you would need to cast it to a bool otherwise it will write out the name.